# Using gulp-inject: How to add query string to injected filename

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to add files to load to index.html. To force browser to reload js-scripts, I want to add a query string to the filename that is injected into index.html.

I suspect this is possible with gulp-inject's transform function. But reading the docs I do not understand how it could be solved. Do you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found out how to do it.

Add a transform function like this:

```
  transform: function (filepath) {
    arguments[0] = filepath + '?v=' + pjson.version;
    return inject.transform.apply(inject.transform, arguments);
  }
```

FYI, I update version number using [gulp-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump) and I get the package info for my app (that include version number) like this: `var pjson = require('./package.json');`

Comment: can you show your full code, as i do not understand where to add that tranform function

Answer (score 4):

based on EricC answer, full code will look something like that:

```
gulp.task('inject', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.html, {cwd: bases.application})
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src([
            bases.build + 'css/styles.min.css',
            bases.build + 'scripts/app.min.js'
        ]), {
            transform: function (filepath) {
                arguments[0] = filepath + '?v=' + app_version;
                return inject.transform.apply(inject.transform, arguments);
            }
        }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.build));
});
```